# how to get NSBezier paths to stroke with a consistant line width

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics

In my NSView subclass in drawRect I stroke a number of NSBezierPaths. I would like the lines drawn as a result of these strokes to have the exact same with, preferably just a couple of pixels wide no matter the scaling of the view. Here's my drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSSize x = [self convertSize:NSMakeSize(1,1) fromView:nil];
    printf("size = %f %f\n", x.width, x.height);
    for(NSBezierPath *path in self.paths) {
        [path setLineWidth:x.width];
        [path stroke];
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of what I am seeing:

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [crb at www.sonic.net](http://www.sonic.net/~crb/snapshot.png))</sub>

Can anyone suggest how I can get the crisp consistant path outlines that I am looking for?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your width fractional?

Comment: It's a float like 12.37, I tried rounding it to the nearest int but that didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try to match the exact pixels of the device. (more difficult since iphone 5)

Do not use coordinates with on half points: like 0.5 (The work on retina, but on "non retina" they are unsharp).

Th eline width goes half to the left / or up, half to the right.

So if you have a lineWidth of 2 and coorinates at integer values it should be sharp.